# build vim binary to run on multiple machines

Tags: vim, compilation

Is there a way to build a vim binary that will work on multiple machines of the same architecture, but with different library configurations? I have a home directory that gets mounted to on multiple machines on which I don't have root access. I wanted to build a personal version of vim in `~/usr/bin`. When I configure it on machine `A`, it runs on `A` but when I try to run it on `B`, it can't find libraries. (likewise if I build it on `B` it runs on `B` but not `A`). Is there a way to combine the configurations or something so that it can find the right libraries on both machines?

Comment: Have you seen this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/644677/vim-binary-with-all-libraries-statically-linked. Or the project on github: https://github.com/ericpruitt/static-vim

Comment: I did not. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(As already outlined in the comments,) you need to build a Vim executable that has all dependencies **statically linked into the binary**. This can be done via `export LDFLAGS='-static'`.

However, according to [static-vim](https://github.com/ericpruitt/static-vim), there's still a dependency on the *glibc* version of the system that build the binary. Said project offers a Makefile that additionally gets rid of that dependency.

Comment: Will this work even if want integration with e.g. python3?